# Can't get auto-disconnect bot to disconnect users already in voice

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to get a discord bot running which will disconnect a specific user from the afk channel on my server whenever they try to enter it.

I admittedly am not very good at coding, and most of what I've got going is pieced together from other help sections I've looked through.

I've managed to get the bot to the state where it'll disconnect the user when they enter the afk channel directly from not being connected, but I am unable to figure out how to get it to do the same when the user moves from a channel to the afk channel.

The section I'm having trouble with is here:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel;
  const oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel;

  if (
    oldUserChannel === undefined &&
    newUserChannel.name === "afk" &&
    data.find(
      guild =>
        guild.id === newMember.guild.id &&
        guild.blacklist.find(id => newMember.id === id)
    )
  ) {
    newMember.setVoiceChannel(null);
  }
```

I've tried setting `oldUserChannel === undefined &&` to specific channels, and !== undefined, but anything other than === undefined gives me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I've also tried user `newUserChannel.id` instead of .name, but that just gives me the same error with 'name' changing to 'id'.

I'm really very new to this, so I'm struggling to think of what I can do to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is being moved to the `AFK` channel from another channel, `oldUserChannel` will be defined as a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel).

You should check if `newUserChannel` exists (if that's the case, we know the user is still connected to a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel), and check if the channel's id/name equals to "AFK" / "Channel ID".

Note: I encourage you to switch to Discord JS v12.

---

```js
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if (!newMember.voiceChannel) return false; // The GuildMember is not in a VoiceChannel.
    if (newMember.voiceChannel.guild.id !== "GUILD ID") return false; // Making sure this works in a certain Guild. I don't think you want this to happen in every Guild your bot is in which has a VoiceChannel called "AFK". 

    if (newMember.voiceChannel.name == "AFK" && newMember.id == "USER ID") { // Checking if the channel's name is AFK and making sure the user is the one you want to disconnect.
        newMember.setVoiceChannel(null);
        // I'm not sure if Discord JS v11 has a method of disconnecting the user from a VoiceChannel.
        // But setting the voice channel to null will work.
    };
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the insight, managed to get it working, thanks a million.